# Side navigation menu responsive class to hide on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey stackoverflow community!

I have a small issue regarding this JS logic to add a class name to my body tag to hide the side navigation menu upon window resizing. Let me try to explain the issue as clearly as I can. Currently I'm using a **UI template by creativetime called Argon**. The page when loaded on a full scaled width looks like this:

[image]

When I resize the window after the page has loaded it looks like this:

[image]

But **when I refresh the page, the side navigation is no longer there as how it should be**, which is like this:

[image]

After refreshing the page, resizing the window thereafter makes the side navigation to hide as it should. **The sidenav just doesn't go hidden on first page load for some reason**.

The JS for this is as follows:

```
    var Layout = (function() {

    function pinSidenav() {
        $('.sidenav-toggler').addClass('active');
        $('.sidenav-toggler').data('action', 'sidenav-unpin');
        $('body').removeClass('g-sidenav-hidden').addClass('g-sidenav-show g-sidenav-pinned');
        $('body').append('<div class="backdrop d-xl-none" data-action="sidenav-unpin" data-target='+$('#sidenav-main').data('target')+' />');

        // Store the sidenav state in a cookie session
        Cookies.set('sidenav-state', 'pinned');
    }

    function unpinSidenav() {
        $('.sidenav-toggler').removeClass('active');
        $('.sidenav-toggler').data('action', 'sidenav-pin');
        $('body').removeClass('g-sidenav-pinned').addClass('g-sidenav-hidden');
        $('body').find('.backdrop').remove();

        // Store the sidenav state in a cookie session
        Cookies.set('sidenav-state', 'unpinned');
    }

    // Set sidenav state from cookie

    var $sidenavState = Cookies.get('sidenav-state') ? Cookies.get('sidenav-state') : 'pinned';

    if($(window).width() > 1200) {
        if($sidenavState == 'pinned') {
            pinSidenav()
        }

        if(Cookies.get('sidenav-state') == 'unpinned') {
            unpinSidenav()
        }

        $(window).resize(function() {
            if( $('body').hasClass('g-sidenav-show') && !$('body').hasClass('g-sidenav-pinned')) {
                $('body').removeClass('g-sidenav-show').addClass('g-sidenav-hidden');
            }
        })
    }

    if($(window).width() < 1200){
      $('body').removeClass('g-sidenav-hide').addClass('g-sidenav-hidden');
      $('body').removeClass('g-sidenav-show');
      $(window).resize(function() {
          if( $('body').hasClass('g-sidenav-show') && !$('body').hasClass('g-sidenav-pinned')) {
              $('body').removeClass('g-sidenav-show').addClass('g-sidenav-hidden');
          }
      })
    }



    $("body").on("click", "[data-action]", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        var action = $this.data('action');
        var target = $this.data('target');


        // Manage actions

        switch (action) {
            case 'search-show':
                target = $this.data('target');
                $('body').removeClass('g-navbar-search-show').addClass('g-navbar-search-showing');

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('body').removeClass('g-navbar-search-showing').addClass('g-navbar-search-show');
                }, 150);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('body').addClass('g-navbar-search-shown');
                }, 300)
            break;

            case 'search-close':
                target = $this.data('target');
                $('body').removeClass('g-navbar-search-shown');

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('body').removeClass('g-navbar-search-show').addClass('g-navbar-search-hiding');
                }, 150);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('body').removeClass('g-navbar-search-hiding').addClass('g-navbar-search-hidden');
                }, 300);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('body').removeClass('g-navbar-search-hidden');
                }, 500);
            break;
        }
    })


    // Add sidenav modifier classes on mouse events

    $('.sidenav').on('mouseenter', function() {
        if(! $('body').hasClass('g-sidenav-pinned')) {
            $('body').removeClass('g-sidenav-hide').removeClass('g-sidenav-hidden').addClass('g-sidenav-show');
        }
    })

    $('.sidenav').on('mouseleave', function() {
        if(! $('body').hasClass('g-sidenav-pinned')) {
            $('body').removeClass('g-sidenav-show').addClass('g-sidenav-hide');

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('body').removeClass('g-sidenav-hide').addClass('g-sidenav-hidden');
            }, 300);
        }
    })


    // Make the body full screen size if it has not enough content inside
    $(window).on('load resize', function() {
        if($('body').height() < 800) {
            $('body').css('min-height', '100vh');
            $('#footer-main').addClass('footer-auto-bottom')
        }
    })

})();
```

Working JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Vaulient/kthw39gs/6/

Comment: Trigger the resize event on page load `$(window).resize(function() {...........}).resize();`  or after all your code use this line `$(window).resize()` or `$(window).trigger('resize')`

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I've already done that as a temporary solution, I've also made a css media query to hide the sidenav upon max-width of 900px, however these are just temporary solutions. I'm trying to figure out the proper solution to this animation problem :)